# How to insert script src within a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, recaptcha

I need to add a script source within a div element. For instance I have the following

```
<div id="recaptcha_div" class="controls">
 // script should go here
</div>
```

The script is as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6Lcc4OYSAAAAABTEzBumk7dNbnpKbpC3JhVdi2yU&amp;hl=en_US"></script>
```

How can I achieve this with JavaScript or jQuery ?

Comment: `$('#recaptcha_div').load()`..????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var elem = document.getElementById("recaptcha_div");
var newScript = document.createElement("script");
newScript.type = "text/javascript";
newScript.src = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6Lcc4OYSAAAAABTEzBumk7dNbnpKbpC3JhVdi2yU&amp;hl=en_US";
elem.appendChild(newScript);
```

Append this JS to your document before closing of body within script tags.

Answer (score 1):

Hithere!

Try the following:

```
document.getElementById("recaptcha_div").innerHTML="<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6Lcc4OYSAAAAABTEzBumk7dNbnpKbpC3JhVdi2yU&amp;hl=en_US'></script>";
```

Goodluck!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var ele = document.getElementById('recaptcha_div');
var js = document.createElement("script");

js.type = "text/javascript";
js.src = jsPath; // your path

ele.appendChild(js);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

$( "#recaptcha_div" ).append( "Your script tag" );